# New to VBA having checkbox problems

Tags: vba, checkbox

So I'm new to programing(2weeks). I am making a data box to find total a price for a project. I works with text boxes, check boxes and a button to find total.

I input the number of lemons and oranges, when I press the button it calculates how much it will cost based on prices that are pulled from the sheet.

Now I put the check box because there is a set quantity of one. I would like to add the price of "sugar" to the total price when it is checked.

Can some one help me get the check box add to total price?

for example the data box looks like this:
 Thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rEvO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MDER.png)

---

New code almost works the way I was hoping. thank you for the advice, I tried referencing the sheet and it gave me errors. But it works like this for now.

-When I input numbers in the input boxes and press calculate it gives me the correct total.
-When I check the check box it adds to the total, BUT when I press "Calc" the total is calculated without including checked box.
-When I press more then one checkbox for example: Select "Checksugar" then "checkbox2" the total only adds the value of "Checkbox2". then when I press "Calc" again, the total ignores the checkboxes.

What im wanting it do: When I select more then one check box, I want the totals to add rather then replace eachother. I also want the code to give the total value when I press "Calc" rather then only the totals of the input boxes.

What I think I need to do: Some how add the If statements in the "TxtTotal", but I do not know how to do that. Or have multiple If statements.

Can someone help?

Private Sub Calculate_Click()

TxtTotal = TxtLemon * Range("E21").Value + TxtLime * Range("E20").Value _
+ TxtOranges * Range("E19").Value _
+ TxtApple * Range("E25").Value _
+ TxtCactus * Range("E24").Value

End Sub

Private Sub Checksugar_Click()
If Me.Checksugar.Value = True Then

```
TxtTotal = TxtLemon * Range("E21").Value + TxtLime * Range("E20").Value _
```

+ TxtOranges * Range("E19").Value _
+ TxtApple * Range("E25").Value _
+ TxtCactus * Range("E24").Value + Range("E22").Value

End If
End Sub

Private Sub Checkbox2_Click()
If Me.Checkbox2.Value = True Then

TxtTotal = TxtLemon * Range("E21").Value + TxtLime * Range("E20").Value _
+ TxtOranges * Range("E19").Value _
+ TxtApple * Range("E25").Value _
+ TxtCactus * Range("E24").Value + Range("E27").Value

End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
 IF CheckSugarValue.Value = True Then
       'do stuff
        TxtTotal.Value = TxtTotal.Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("your sheet name).Range("E22").Value
 End if
```

You have a realloy bad habit of non reference stuff correctly. Since youre new its best to understand now while you can form good habits. Converting control objects contents to usable values is often done with ".Value" and often times most people will store those values in a variable. Your lack of explicitly referring to a sheet name will get you into some big trouble later b/c ambiguous references will make the compiler look at wrong sheets. I just got into the habit of doing it the long way like in my example.

Comment: Thank you, the "do stuff" ,is what im stuck on. How do I make the check box add to the total amount when selected?